# How do I make a self locating batch file

Tags: batch-file

So basicly I want to make a batch file that can execute other files, while learing its own location on execution.
It should then use it own path as a reference to the other files.
How should I go about coding that or are there any guides for exactly that?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: A batch file is referenced with `%0`. You most often would use modifiers with that too, _(take a look at the output from entering `call /?` at the Command Prompt, to see those modifiers, and replace the `1` with `0` as necessary)_.

Comment: there are a lot of duplicates: [Get current batchfile directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17063947/995714), [How do I find the current directory of a batch file, and then use it for the path?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16255184/995714), [How to get the path of the batch script in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3827567/995714)...

Answer (score 0):

The batch file name as entered via command line is stored in %0. Using file expander to get other parts. You can put the following code into a batch file and try it out:

```
REM print batch filename as user entered
echo %0
REM print full file name: d - drive, p - path, f - filename
echo %~dpf0
REM print path only
echo %~dp0
```

The current directory is stored in %CD%, in case you need it.

Comment: Your answer needs revising. Take a look at the output from entering `call /?` for assistance with it.